# Alternative to Avast Safezone for banking

Tags: web-browser, keyloggers

Apparently low level keyloggers etc can intercept typed details before Safezone keylogging protection kicks in. Would BD Safepay avoid this problem with its enforced virtual keyboard ? Or perhaps Sandboxied browser with real time Zemena antilogger encryption and MBAE injected . Which safest option please for banking .

Answer (score 1):

> Would BD Safepay avoid this problem with its enforced virtual keyboard ?

**Not completely**: It would mean that actual keyloggers would no longer be able to intercept your keystrokes. In fact, this is why some banks require you [to enter your password by clicking on-screen buttons](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22774/my-bank-makes-me-enter-my-password-using-the-mouse-whats-up-with-that?rq=1). However, keyloggers have adapted, and some have also become "mouseloggers", which means that even with a virtual, on-screen keyboard you may not be safe, since these will take screenshots of what and where you click.

> Or perhaps Sandboxied browser with real time Zemena antilogger encryption and MBAE injected

**Not really**: It will make your environment more secure, but it *won't gurantee anything*. Zemena is basically an antivirus, and, if it does not detect the keylogger, you're out of luck. MBAE is similar: It won't help you if it doesn't detect the malware.

Tl;Dr: "Low-level" keyloggers could intercept your keystrokes and any other actions, *no matter what you do.*

**What I'd recommend,** as a "kind of" alternative: Use a system which you know is not infected for your online banking. A Linux live CD could be used for this purpose. Also, If Avast or another antivirus tells you that you're safe, *you probably are.*

Comment: Thanks but BD moderators state that screenshots cannot possibly be taken by screenscrapers to capture screen data .Safepay intercepts and blocks all combinations of Printscreen which is disabled by default.

Comment: There's other ways to capture the screen. If a piece of malware run with admin privileges it can direct read the screen memory.